REST API call - cvent 401 error Code
I'm trying to write a CVENT REST API call in my code. According to the documentation, I'm sending all the required parameters. The same request works perfectly in Postman, but in my code, it returns a 401 response code.
Can you please help me what I am missing here.
https://developer-portal.cvent.com/documentation#tag/Contacts/operation/listContactsPostFilters
Note: I have a separate method to generate the access token, and it works perfectly.
public static string GetListContacts(string email, string accessToken){
 accessToken = getAuthToken();        
List<Contact> updateContactStub = new List<Contact>();
        String requestBody = '{"filter": "email eq \'' + email + '\'"}'; 
        // Set up the HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:CventAuthCred/ea/contacts/filter');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', accessToken);
        req.setBody(requestBody); 
        // Send the HTTP request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res;
        try {
            res = http.send(req);
            system.debug('requestBody -->' + requestBody);
            system.debug('requestBody -->' + req);
            system.debug('response -->' + res.getBody());
            system.debug('Response Code -->' + res.getStatusCode());
            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                GetContactResponse responseList = (GetContactResponse) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), GetContactResponse.class);
                if(responseList.paging.totalCount > 0){
                    List<data> dataList = responseList.data;
                    if(dataList.size() > 0){
                        return  dataList[0].id; 
                    }
                } 
            }
            return '';        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            return '';
        }  
    }

Response:
response -->{"error":{"code":"401","message":"No credentials provided"}}
Auth Token
public static String getAuthToken() {
        // Create the HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:CventAuthCred/ea/oauth2/token');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials');
        
        // Create the HTTP client and send the request
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug('Res Code -->' + req);
        system.debug('Res Code -->' + res.getStatusCode());
        // Check the response status
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Parse the JSON response to extract the token
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            String accessToken = (String) resultMap.get('access_token');
            return 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
        } else {
            // Handle the error appropriately
            System.debug('Error: ' + res.getStatus() + ' ' + res.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('Response: ' + res.getBody());
            return null;
        }
    }


Named Credentials:

Postman


Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. Let's start with editing your question and showing the Postman call, the details of your Named Credential config, the call to get the access token (you say it works but proof is in the pudding)

@identigral Added the Screenshot of Postman and Named Credentials

I don't know why in getAuthToken() you return 
'Bearer ' + accessToken; \ and in GetListContacts you use \ req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);? \ Maybe a double Bearer caused the problem? Note: I'm sorry that I don't have enough 50 reputations for comment.

I tried adding Bearer  in the getAuthToken method and checked just for POC, I edited my question

Have you tried hard coding the URL to check it? I think the named credential caused the error.

link In Named Credential I saw you are using Password Authentication, maybe it overrides your Authorization header.

Any way to resolve this issue, Not sure what I am missing

Use  req.setEndpoint('https://api-platform.cvent.com/ea/contacts/filter'); instead.
